# How to set only Math fonts to Times in a Beamer document?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, times

I'm using default Latex Fonts (lmodern, serif) to the main body of the document, but I'd like to set ONLY math mode to Times, leaving the rest unaltered. Which package should I use?

Thanks. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: You state that "default Latex Fonts (lmodern, serif)" are used in your `beamer` document. By default, `beamer` uses **sans-serif** Computer Modern/Latin Modern. Did you already change the default font set? If so, how did you bring about the changed setup?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've switched  the default Beamer font to a standard Latex document one. I used " \usefonttheme{serif}" in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use `unicode-math` if you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts if you have to.

If you can use `unicode-math`, add the command

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

If you are using PDFTeX, load the package

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

You might need to give `beamer` the `professionalfonts` option to turn off sans-serif math.